# GROOVY - Getting Gregorian Date Instead of Date from sql.rows

Tags: sql, database, select, groovy, rows

I am trying to do, in groovy, a Select on my DB using:

`sql.rows(selectRowsStatement)`

The problem is that I am getting Date in the format:
017-03-02 00:00:00.000
 instead of 
2017-03-02.

The point is the datatype definition in the DB of that column is "DATE" and not "DateTime" or "Timestamp".

Any idea how to get Date instead of DateTime?

Comment: what's the underlying DB?

Comment: @MikeW The DB is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with formatting and just want the date, use to_char with appropriate format e.g.

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: How this could be included in my query: ´select * from TABLE ORDER BY RECORD_ID ASC ´

Comment: You'll have to specify the fields individually or you could do `select table.*, to_char( your_date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD') mydate from table order by record_id` so you'll end up with all the fields and the formatted date.

Comment: The problem is that with the select I extract not Date, it extract several data that I need

Comment: Sorry lost me there.

Comment: I mean, I could apply what you have suggested in the case I am selecting only one column and then do to_char( your_date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD') . But I am doing a select * on a table with 200 columns where 15 of them are date how could I use your suggested statement?

Comment: Wow that's a wide table, as mentioned, `select table.*, to_char( date_field_1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') df1, to_char( date_field_2, 'YYYY-MM-DD') df2 from table` and so on, the `table.*` statement selects all columns then we're appending conversions of each date column, you'll still get the date fields as per your original question but you can ignore them, the other way is to select all fields individually and convert the dates

Answer (score 0):

If you need a GregorianCalendar instance try this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String dateString = '017-03-02 00:00:00.000'
String datePattern = 'yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
calendar.time = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).parse(dateString)
```

But if you need an ordinary date, so:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String dateString = '017-03-02 00:00:00.000'
String datePattern = 'yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).parse(dateString)
```

Comment: I ddidn't understand how this can resolve my problem. I am doing  select * on a table with 300 columns where 10 of them are Date ( in the oracle definition) and grovy translate it automatically in '2017-03-02 00:00:00.000' instead of '2017-03-02'.